# Triangle separators between divs with transparent backgrounds

Tags: css

I'd like to add triangle seperators between the sections of a page. Each section has a transparent background color.

There's a parent div that wraps around the sections and has a fixed background image.

Example of what I'm trying to achieve: 
[image]

I'm having trouble positioning the seperator/arrow and creating the white border around it.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Site Name</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">   
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="section-1 downarrow">
                <p>Section 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="section-2">
                <p>Section 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="section-3">
                <p>Section 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,p,blockquote,th,td {margin:0;padding:0;}
table {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
fieldset,img {border:0;}
ul {list-style:none; list-style-position:outside;}
a {outline: none;}

.wrapper {
    background-image: url('bg.jpg');  
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.section-1 {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: rgba(12, 85, 184, .9);    
}

.section-2 {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: rgba(95, 20, 20, .9);
}

.section-3 {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: rgba(12, 85, 184, .9);
}

.downarrow:after,.downarrow:before {
    content: ''; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 50%; 
    z-index: 100; 
    border-bottom: 40px solid #fff; 
    -moz-transform: rotate(0.000001deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0.000001deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(0.000001deg); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(0.000001deg);
    transform: rotate(0.000001deg)
}

 .downarrow:before {
    right: 50%; 
    border-right: 40px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 1000px solid #fff;
}
 .downarrow:after {
    left: 50%; 
    border-left: 40px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 1000px solid #fff;
}

 .downarrow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use svg image for it, or do you need css only?

Comment: Yes, I can use an svg image.

Comment: @user22939 just posted answer for your query. Please review.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the updated one, i made some efforts to make it a look like as per the example image provided. please review the code. Hope it is helpful to you.

Note: Please update dimensions accordingly as per requirement. It is just a dummy.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height:300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.wrap img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom:3%;
  margin-top: -3%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.arrow:before, .arrow:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom:inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
}
.arrow:before {
  right: 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform: skewX(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  border-right: 3px solid #fff;
  margin-right:-2px;
}
.arrow:after {
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  border-left: 3px solid #fff;
  margin-left:-2px;
}



.arrow1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom:3%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-bottom: -3%;
}
.arrow1:before, .arrow1:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom:inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
}
.arrow1:before {
  right: 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform: skewX(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  border-right: 3px solid #fff;
  margin-right:-2px;
}
.arrow1:after {
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  border-left: 3px solid #fff;
  margin-left:-2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="arrow1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at the code I posted, it needs to look like that but with the dividers in the proper place. Also, take note of how the parent div has a fixed background when scrolling up and down using my code.